# I am working on an e-commerce site and I am having trouble debugging

Tags: javascript, html, module, e-commerce, hugo

I am working on a site with some purchasing forms and I am trying to get them all to display in one container. They work when they arnt together so I am thinking its a declaration issue. I honestly can not figure it out though.

https://jsfiddle.net/Popo74123/fwpavo82/22/

**FAIR WARNING**

There is ALOT of code in the fiddle. On my site I have it seperated into modules that an html file calls each one individually.

Right now this is the main error I am getting.
`<a class='gotoLine' href='#1225:50'>1225:50</a> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'type' of null"`

I had this error earlier and fixed it by changing one of the prevBstBtn ids to the correct name. I can not find what is triggering this one though.

Comment: It appears the error is from this line: document.getElementById("ppPltBtn").type = "image"; since there is no element with id ppPltBtn

Comment: Awesome thank you! I was thinking it was else where like the other was. Now what it is doing is that every next button controls the first div. So I am thinking more duplicate variables in the step functions? Here is the updated fiddle with the typeerrors gone. https://jsfiddle.net/Popo74123/fwpavo82/